# Python - function to do string comparison

Tags: python, string-comparison

```
def name(x):
    return x==('Jenson'or'Amra'or'McCay'or'Spinner'or'Jones')
print(name('Jenson'))
print(name('McCay'))
```

This is the question:

> "Write a function that takes as input a name of a person (e.g.,
>   “smith”, “jones”, etc.) This function should  check to see if the name
>   is one of the five names of people on the board. The five names are:
>   “Jenson”,”Amra”,  “McCay”,”Spinner”, and “Jones”. If the name input
>   into the function is one of those five names, the function  should
>   return the Boolean value True, and if it isn’t, the function should
>   return False. (remember comments  with input types, description, and
>   test cases) Test the function to make sure it works."

It works if I am doing Jenson but it comes out with false if I put in any other name.

Comment: Also what is my way interpreting so I can understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Why don't you post your code snippet so that everyone can take a look what is missing or going wrong ?

Comment: In reference to your (deleted) question just now, please don't delete questions once you've asked them - people took time to help you, and you just deleted their comment responses. There were several items of genuine assistance in that thread, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the "long" way:

```
def check_name(x):
   names_to_check = ('Jenson','Amra','McCay','Spinner','Jones')
   for i in names_to_check:
       if i == x:
          return True
   return False
```

Here is what is happening in your code:

`x = 'Jenson'`, since this is what you have passed in.

This line `x == ('Jenson' or 'Amra' or 'McCay' or 'Jones')` is actually a boolean operation, and *the result* of it is always `Jenson`.

Boolean operations check *truth values*, and a non-empty string in Python is always `True`. So actually what `('Jenson' or 'Amra' or 'McCay' or 'Jones')` is saying is:

*"Either `Jenson` or `Amra` or `McCay` or `Jones` which ever one is `True`, set the value to that".*

Since `Jenson` is the first item, and its `True` (that is, its not an empty string), the entire expression is equal to `Jenson` (which is why it only works when you pass in `Jenson`).

A simple example:

```
>>> ('a' or 'b' or 'c')
'a'
>>> ('b' or 'a' or 'c')
'b'
>>> ('' or '' or 'a')
'a'
>>> (0 or 0 or 1)
1
>>> (False or False or True)
True
```

The last three illustrate the same comparison. I am checking two empty strings and `'a'`. Since an empty string is `False` in Python, the only thing that is "True" is `'a'`, which is what is returned, just as if I was comparing `0` with `1`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation

Answer (score 4):

Try like this,

```
def name(x):
    return x in ('Jenson', 'Amra' ,'McCay', 'Spinner','Jones')
```

Comment: Use the `in` operator and give them a big surprise ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax x==('Jenson' or 'Amra' or 'McCay' or 'Spinner'or'Jones') is wrong.
It should be like Adem says. or maybe

```
def name(x):
    return x=='Jenson' or x== 'Amra' or x  == 'McCay' or x == 'Spinner' or x == 'Jones'
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine what is happening is that `('Jenson'or'Amra'or'McCay'or'Spinner'or'Jones')` is being evaluated first, and is evaluated to `'Jenson'`.  That is computed before `x` is even considered because it is in parentheses.  Then `x` is checked for equality against `Jenson`.  You need to either use a more advanced syntax like `x in...` as in Adem's answer, or else use `return x == 'Jenson' or x == 'Amra' or x == 'McCay'...` so that each comparison is run one after another.

Comment: Actually, `('Jenson'or'Amra'or'McCay'or'Spinner'or'Jones')` evaluates to `'Jenson'` which is why Jenson works, but everything else returns False

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect that so as not to confuse the OP.  Thank you for the correction.